# Count filled cells in a certain rows in each column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to count filled cells from each column and from row 14 to 45.
I'm using below code to find the count of filled cells in a fixed range but unable to check for each column as I'm unable to make 1st row in range type `cells(row,column)` format. Any help please.

```
Range("A14", Range("A14").End(xlDown)).Select
m = Selection.Rows.Count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand, but this will look at everything between A14 and the last filled cell in A:

```
msgbox worksheetfunction.counta(range("A14",range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup)))
```

If for several columns perhaps this?

```
Sub x()

Dim c As Long

For c = 1 To 10 'A to J
    MsgBox WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(14, c), Cells(45, c)))
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Can we limit `MsgBox WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(14, 4), Range("4" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)))` to count till 45 row no.?

Comment: Why not just `range("A14:A45")` then? `Cells(14, 4)` is D14 though.

Comment: I've to get count from each column. Basically I'm printing the rows from each column from that range and I'm counting cells for this reason so that I can use it in `for...next` loop. Filled cells from column are different.

Comment: Do you mean you want to count the number of filled cells between row 14 and 45 in several different columns?

Comment: Yes. If above line can be in format `cells(row, column)` I can achieve what I want.